# Spark Streaming REST Custom Receiver

Tags: rest, apache-spark, datasource, spark-streaming

Is it possible to use a REST API in a custom receiver for Spark Streaming?

I am trying to be able to do multiple calls / reads from that API asynchronously and use Spark Streaming to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom receiver can be whatever process that produces data asynchronously. Typically, your `def receive()` method will send async requests to your REST server, maybe using `Futures` and a dedicated `ThreadPool`. `onCompletion` of the future, we call the `store(data)` method to give the results to the Spark Streaming job.
In a nutshell,

- `def onStart()` => creates the process that manages the async request response handling
- `def receive()` => continuously does the I/O and reports the results through calling `store(...)`
- `def onStop()` => stops the process and cleans up what `onStart` creates.

There's an example in the [custom receivers docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html).

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of using some external implementation (was looking into Flume) to get data into something like Kafka first and use Kafka as a source for my Spark Streaming app, but it seems like I can get this to work just fine.

Comment: @maasg any idea what the best object type coming off of a request like this would be? For instance, a string of the raw json, a structured pojo, something else?